# find 3 equal elements between variable array and set of constant Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I am building a tic tac toe game. I am currently trying to write the function to check if someone has won the game. I have an object with a set of data including a multidimensional array with all the combinations of winning "numbers" that relate to squares on the board. Each time you click a square the number of the square is pushed into a separate array for each player.

My problem is currently in looping through and finding out when this array containing the players current squares is equal to one of the winning number arrays.

I have tried a lot of different ways around this including, different variations of nested for loops, using includes, using indexOf, and then either trying to console log a win message or push a random value to a separate array / variable which when reaching 3 would signal a win, but really I am having a mind meltdown now and would like any advice anyone can give.

```
   var game = {

   player: true,
   win: [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,5],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]], 
   //the above is my array of winning combinations
   p1Points: 0,
   p2Points: 0,
   p1Moves:[], //the place for players "moves" to be stored
   p2Moves:[]
        }

    function currentMove(square){
       var squareNum = square.data('squarenumber');
       square.off();
          if(game.player){
            square.html('x'); 
            game.p1Moves.push(squareNum);
            game.player = false;
           checkWin(game.win, game.p1Moves)
      }

      else{
            square.html('0');
            game.p2Moves.push(squareNum);
            game.player = true;}
            checkWin(game.win, game.p2Moves)
   }

   function checkWin(winArr, movesArr){

   /* this is the function I need help with, have tried multiple things
   it needs to return somthing to signal a player has won. e.g three in a 
   row. */




   }
```

Comment: you could add you best try, just to find out what is going wrong with your search.

Comment: Sure sorry I am just trying to rewrite my best, I did it in a codepen and it wouldnt go back far enough for me to find so ill just have another go now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest storing the players moves in an object rather than in an array, to ease comparisons afterwards. So you'll have:

```
 if(game.player){
     square.html('x'); 

     // use indexed object
     game.p1Moves[squareNum] = true;

     game.player = false;
     checkWin(game.win, game.p1Moves)
 }
```

and now,

```
/**
 * Checks winning combination
 *
 * @param winArr Array of Array[3] of Winning Moves 
 * @param movesObj Object with moves
 */

function checkWin(winArr, movesObj) {

    // iterate through all Winning Combinations
    for (var i = 0, l = winArr.length; i<l; i++) {

        var combArray = winArr[i],    // *each* of the winning combination arrays
            count=0;                  // success counter for every combination

        // check winning move: all squares in player object must be full
        for (var j=0; j<3; j++) 
            if (movesObj[combArray[j]]) count++;

        // current winning move ok if its 3 squares full
        if (count == 3) return true;
    }

    // no winning move found
    return false;

}
```

or in a most efficient version:

```
function checkWin(winArr, movesObj) {

    // iterate through all Winning Combinations
    for (var i = 0, count = 0, l = winArr.length; i < l; i++, count = 0) {

        // check winning move: all squares in player object must be full
        for (var j=0; j<3; j++) ( movesObj[winArr[i][j]] && (count++) );

        // current winning move ok if its 3 squares full
        if (count == 3) return true;
    }

    // no winning move found
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks, just to check, the for (var..) part, where you have an l = win arr .length, I have never seen this but essentially your assigning the length to variable l , correct?

Comment: yeah, that's for efficiency, as otherwise you would be checking are.length on every iteration, which is slower

Comment: awesome thats really interesting, your solution works very well, butl another part I just need to get to grips with its the var comb = winArr[i], count = 0; so this combines the individual winArr array with a count of zero? how does that work, when i console.log(comb) I get a list of arrays> are these the possible arrays left to win? I have a relative understanding of the process but any more clarification would be fantastic

Comment: I've clarified it a little. The "comma" in the `var` is just to declare several vars at once (more efficient). I reset count to 0 for every winning move. Then I check the current winning move array. I increment "count" if the player has used that square. If, at the end of the loop, count is 3, then whr winning move is complete. If it's not, it's incomplete. The outer loop fetches the next one if any. If not, it returns false. All winning combinations are incomplete.

Comment: An additional point of improvement is to use the same MoveArray for both players, but one fills with "1" and another one with "2". The checker routine will accept one additional parameter, "player", and the loop will check for content == player. This way you can expand the game to an unlimited number of players, if it would make sense.

Comment: Wow yeh I really like that, nice idea, and thank you so much for all the clarification I am going to deconstruct and try to write my own version using a similar methodology :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function checkWin(winArr, movesArr){
  return winArr.some(function(win) {
    return win.join('') === movesArr.join('')
  })
}
```

This will return `true/false`, if the winning combination was found.

Edit: 
As @rupps mentioned, don't forget to sort it to keep consistency in the order.

`return win.join('') === movesArr.sort().join('')`

Comment: you would need to sort the array before, or else move order will ruin your comparisons.

Comment: @rupps Thanks. Updated the answer

Comment: What do you mean? Care to elaborate?

Comment: yeh I cant seem to get it to work, even with the sort()

Comment: The movesArr array is rerturning without a comma between elements and the winArr has a comma between each

Comment: Also if the the number of turns is more than three to get a win, this method doesnt work

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but comma doesn't really matter here. [1,2,3].join('') = '123'. Having it iterated it over a 2-d Array. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] will give '123' and '456'. So, I don't understand the comma problem. But you are right about the win count, I knowingly did not address it, I just wanted to give him an idea about how to match the arrays.

Comment: What I meant was, when I console.log the 2-d array it did not give 123 but "1,2,3", which I admit is very strange and I couldn't figure out why, but if the comma is removed and they are straight numbers and put toString this works, except as we both agree the other issue